# Can MSE (and SO) chat notify me on other sites’ chats?

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

Recently, I’ve been trying to check the Tavern on the Meta, along with rooms on other Chat sites, at the same time. However, on MSE chatrooms, the accounts are separate from non-MSE ones. If I am in one room, e.g. The Restaurant at the End of the Universe (on SFF), and someone replies to me or @s me in the Tavern, there is no feedback or anything in the Restaurant tab. This is annoying, especially on mobile, where I can’t see other tabs’ names update very easily.

**Can notifications for the different Chat domains be unified between MSE, SO, and normal sites, like the global inbox is?**